# Two rounding methods give different results

Tags: ruby, floating-point, rounding, floating-accuracy

Two different rounding methods of floats show different results.

```
"%.2f" % 0.015 # => "0.01" 
0.015.round(2) # => 0.02
```

One is string and the other a float. When rounding anything but 0.5, it rounds correctly or rather the same way as the round function.

```
"%.2f" % 0.01500000000000001 # => "0.02"
```

Also, it doesn't always behave like that:

```
[0.005, 0.015, 0.025, 0.035, 0.045, 0.055, 0.065, 0.075, 0.085, 0.095].map { |x| "%.2f" % x}
# => ["0.01", "0.01", "0.03", "0.04", "0.04", "0.06", "0.07", "0.07", "0.09", "0.10"]
```

I am not sure if this is technically a bug, but at least it is very counter intuitive. Does anybody know why two rounding methods act that differently?

Comment: Which [rounding method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) are you looking to find? If you use a consistent method for rounding you'll get consistent results.

Comment: In one case I needed it to stay a float, in the other I needed a string instead. Having two different results was counter intuitive and caused some bad bugs.

Comment: It's not a bug, but an artifact of how crazy floating point numbers can be since some values cannot be represented accurately, only approximated. It's a lot safer to use fixed point math, or something like BigDecimal that's designed to be slower but more consistent.

Comment: I'm not a ruby expert, but searching some ruby documentation for sprintf, I see nothing that guarantees sprintf implements rounding as part of printing floats at a specified precision. Perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @tadman: Binary isn't "crazy."

Comment: @tmyklebu It is pretty crazy when there's a number of different representations for the same numerical value, and they can't be compared for equivalence, among other things. Floating point has to be presumed to be an approximation, not a literal representation.

Comment: @tadman: There's one representation for every floating-point number except zero.  You can tell the two signed zeroes apart (if you ever need to) by comparing their reciprocals to zero.  Binary floating-point is great at representing certain values exactly.  There is no reason to presume anything's approximate when it isn't.

Comment: The question and answers seem to be focusing on the behaviour of the `"%.2f"` formatting.  However, technically it's the `round` method that's "wrong" here.  The value stored internally for the literal `0.015` is actually a touch less than `0.015` (it's 0.01499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375, to be exact), so if anything the rounding operation should round *down* to `0.01`.  Ruby is using a somewhat naive rounding algorithm which is not correctly rounded.  (N.B. That doesn't make it a bug, unless Ruby's docs claim to do correct rounding here.)

Comment: As to the formatting: I haven't checked, but it's likely that Ruby is simply using the OS-supplied functionality (`dtoa`, `sprintf` and the like) for this.  Typically, the results of that *will* be correctly rounded, modulo obscure corner cases and OS library bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Floating values aren't always stored exactly -- they are instead stored as a base and exponent which for some numbers is stored exactly and others is not. Any modifications to the float *can* cause a very small fraction to appear. Thus rounding something right at a boundary with different rounding functions can make it switch between the two possible results.

Doing `"%.2f" % 0.015.round(2)` will give you the `0.02` result you wanted, as I am guessing the `%.2f` is implemented differently than the floating round method.

Comment: There's a lot of tradition behind how `%` and `sprintf`-like operations should behave, that inherits from the implementation in C. Could be that it's just implementing that behaviour consistently.

Comment: That's very likely - it's also possible that %.2f assumes a certain byte-size float/double which differs from the actual type used by particular ruby interpreters and a cast to match the sprintf/C type is done.

Comment: I am using "%.2f" % 0.015.round(2) for now as a work around. The real problem IMO is the unexpected difference between the two methods though.

Comment: Well one is a coercion to string, the other is a coercion to another float (which is then coerced to a string for printing to console) so technically the two methods are not equivalent logically speaking.